# Use jCarousel with an Image field?

Tags: 7, media

The [jCarousel](http://drupal.org/project/jcarousel) plugin looks like it's mostly used with Views, but I'd like to use it (or something like it) for a simple Image field which has multiple images in it.

Do you know of a way to do this or another module which behaves this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For nodes image field you can use [Field Slideshow module](http://drupal.org/project/field_slideshow) with your JCarousel
it solves your problem

Comment: Great, I'll check that out.

Answer (score 0):

[Views slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) will do the job for you:

> Views Slideshow can be used to create a slideshow of any content (not
>   just images) that can appear in a View. Powered by jQuery, it is
>   heavily customizable: you may choose slideshow settings for each View
>   you create.

Comment: I don't want to use Views for this, I'm just rendering a simple node with fields.